# FaceBook PageTab Questions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'll get right to it... 
First i can't get an event to fire after a pagetab is added

```
    var url=window.location + '?recheck=true';
    var obj = {
       method: 'pagetab',
       redirect_uri: url
    };
    FB.ui(obj);
```

Don't know why i even bother specifying a redirect_url if the redirect doesn't even work.

Simple enough... i've tried

```
FB.ui(obj, function(result){
    alert(result);// nothing happens
});
```

---

And a second question. When adding pagetabs it only allows the facebook user to add the pagetab to the pages they administer but not to their default profile page. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Why don’t you just do the redirect yourself?
2. Nope. Page tabs are available for fan pages only, not for user profiles.

Comment: how do i know when to redirect? that's the problem.. what if they canceled ? i need to know when to redirect.

Comment: And what is your criteria for _when_ you actually do want to redirect …?

Comment: after the user selects page and clicks [add page tab] in the facebook dialog? it doesn't have to redirect if i can get an event to fire after pagetab is added i can do what i want from there